# Объединить два запроса Oracle (Добавить строку итогов в запрос)

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть два относительно одинаковых запроса. Второй запрос выводит суммарные данные первого.
Нельзя ли как-то их оптимизировать и выполнять все в одном запросе? И выводить сумму в конце каждого столбца?

Основной запрос:

```
select round(hz,2) HZ,bz,round(h0,1)HO,naim,
 round(sum(pf),2) PF,round(sum(pt),2) PT,
 round(sum(pdm),2) PDM,round(sum(pdp),2) PDP,round(sum(pbm),2)PBM,round(sum(pbp),2) PBP,
 round(sum(tp)/60,2) TP,round(sum(pf)/sum(tp)*60,1)SFP
 from (select r.hz,r.bz,r.h0,m.naim,r.pf,r.pt,r.pdm,r.pdp,r.pbm ,r.pbp,
 case when ((r.tz-p.ts)*1440 < 10) and ((r.i_rez3/60) < 10) then (case when r.n > 1 then ((r.ts-p.ts)*1440) else ((r.ts-r.tz)*1440) end)
 when ((r.tz-p.ts)*1440 > 10) and ((r.i_rez3/60) < 10) then (case when r.n > 1 then (((r.ts-r.tz)*1440)+10) else((r.ts-r.tz)*1440)end) 
 when ((r.tz-p.ts)*1440 < 10) and ((r.i_rez3/60) > 10) then (case when r.n > 1 then ((((r.ts-p.ts)*1440)-(r.i_rez3/60-10)))else((((r.ts-r.tz)*1440)-(r.i_rez3/60-10))) end)
 when ((r.tz-p.ts)*1440 > 10) and ((r.i_rez3/60) > 10) then (case when r.n > 1 then ((((r.ts-r.tz))*1440+10-(r.i_rez3/60-10))) else((((r.ts-r.tz))*1440-(r.i_rez3/60-10)))end) end as tp
 from zxp.rulon r,zxp.mc m,zxp.rulon p
 where
r.ts between to_date('14.04.16 22:00:00','dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss') and to_date('15.04.16 7:00:00','dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss')+1 
  and r.ms = m.ukey
 and p.ts = (
   select max(pp.ts)
   from zxp.rulon pp 
   where pp.ts <= r.tz 
     and pp.ts > r.tz-1))
 group by hz,h0,bz,naim
 order by hz,h0,bz,naim
```

Дублирующий с суммой:

```
select 'Итого:',round(sum(pf),2)"Р физ.",round(sum(pt),2)"Р теор.",
 round(sum(pdm),2)"Р доп. -",round(sum(pdp),2)"Р доп. +",round(sum(pbm),2)"Р бр. -",round(sum(pbp),2)"Р бр. +",
 round(sum(tp)/60,2)"Длит.",round(sum(pf)/sum(tp)*60,1)"Произв."
 from (select 
 r.pf,r.pt,r.pdm,r.pdp,r.pbm,r.pbp,
 case when ((r.tz-p.ts)*1440 < 10) and ((r.i_rez3/60) < 10) then (case when r.n > 1 then ((r.ts-p.ts)*1440) else ((r.ts-r.tz)*1440) end)
 when ((r.tz-p.ts)*1440 > 10) and ((r.i_rez3/60) < 10) then (case when r.n > 1 then (((r.ts-r.tz)*1440)+10) else((r.ts-r.tz)*1440)end) 
 when ((r.tz-p.ts)*1440 < 10) and ((r.i_rez3/60) > 10) then (case when r.n > 1 then ((((r.ts-p.ts)*1440)-(r.i_rez3/60-10)))else((((r.ts-r.tz)*1440)-(r.i_rez3/60-10))) end)
 when ((r.tz-p.ts)*1440 > 10) and ((r.i_rez3/60) > 10) then (case when r.n > 1 then ((((r.ts-r.tz))*1440+10-(r.i_rez3/60-10))) else((((r.ts-r.tz))*1440-(r.i_rez3/60-10)))end) end as tp
 from zxp.rulon r,zxp.rulon p
 where     r.ts between to_date('14.04.16 22:00:00','dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss') and to_date ('15.04.16 7:00:00','dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss')  and 
 p.ts =(select max(pp.ts) from zxp.rulon pp where pp.ts <= r.tz and pp.ts > r.tz-1))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте функцию [`ROLLUP`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/aggreg.htm) при группировке, она умеет подводить промежуточные итоги по указанным колонкам. Если нам нужен итог только по части колонок из group by, то оставшиеся следует заключить в дополнительные скобки. Т.к. вы хотите получить только общий итог - то все колонки надо заключить в дополнительные скобки в rollup. Примерно так:

```
select round(hz,2) HZ,bz,round(h0,1)HO,naim, .....
  from ...
 group by ROLLUP((hz,h0,bz,naim))  --<---- Колонки в двойных скобках для общего итога !!!
 order by hz,h0,bz,naim
```

В итоговой записи все колонки указанные к группировке будут иметь значение NULL, что можно использовать для вывода надписей 'Итого' и т.п. Или используйте функцию `grouping(колонка)` которая вернет 1 - если данная строка итог или 0 - если это строка данных.

Comment: Спасибо, но это не совсем то что мне нужно, видимо придется оставлять два почти одинаковых запроса.

Comment: @Ethernets Почему не совсем то, можно вывести значение grouping(hz) и заключить все это вместе во внешний запрос, который на основании этого поля переставит колонки как надо и добавит красивые надписи. Или чем у вас еще итоговый запрос отличается

Comment: делением round(sum(tp)/60,2)"Длит.",round(sum(pf)/sum(tp)*60,1)"Произв." Смысл я понял почитаю как на практике реализовать

Comment: @Ethernets Не вижу отличий, в первом запросе вы то же делите. А сумма деленных значений равна делению суммы (кроме особенностей округления)

Comment: Разобрался, все работает как нужно, Большое спасибо